# AJAX success response is not working but it's saving my changes

Tags: wordpress

I'm a beginner in jQuery-Ajax so please bear with me. My Ajax response does not seem to load but my changes are being saved. but gives me this error on admin-ajax.php "***call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_update_post_ter_count' not found or invalid function name***".
Here is my function, could you point what i'm doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_sort', 'ccmanz_save_reorder' );
add_action('wp_ajax_save_sort','ccmanz_save_reorder');
function ccmanz_save_reorder() { //checking

    //verify user intent
    check_ajax_referer( 'wp-job-order', 'security' ); // this comes from wp_localize_script() in hrm-jobs.php
    //capability check to ensure use caps
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have permission to access this page.' ) );
    }

    $order   = explode( ',', $_POST['order'] );
    $counter = 0;

    foreach ( $order as $item_id ) {
        $post = array(
            'ID'         => (int) $item_id,
            'menu_order' => $counter,
        );

        wp_update_post( $post );
        $counter ++;
    }
    wp_send_json_success('POST SAVED');
}
```

My Ajax Call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    sortList = $( 'ul#custom-type-list' ); //store
    var animation = $ ( '#loading-animation' );
    var pageTitle = $ ( 'div h2');

    sortList.sortable({

        update: function ( event, ui) {
            animation.show();

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, // ajaxurl is defined by WordPress and points to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                    action: 'save_sort', // Tell WordPress how to handle this ajax request
                    order: sortList.sortable( 'toArray' ).toString(), // Passes ID's of list items in   1,3,2 format
                    security: WP_JOB_LISTING.security
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    animation.hide();
                    $('div.updated').remove();
                    if( true === response.success ) {
                        console.log(sortList.sortable( 'toArray' ));
                        pageTitle.after(  
                        '<div id="messsage" class="updated"><p>' + WP_JOB_LISTING.success + '</p></div>'
                        );
                    } else {
                        $('div.error').remove();
                        pageTitle.after( '<div id="messsage" class="error"><p>' + WP_JOB_LISTING.failure + '</div>' );
                    }

                },
                error: function ( error ) {
                    $( 'div.error' ).remove();
                    animation.hide();
                    //pageTitle.after( '<div id="messsage" class="error"><p>' + WP_JOB_LISTING.failure + '</div>' );
                }
            });

        }//update

    }); //sortable

});//jquery
```

Comment: wrong forum:  Should be over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay mate. Thanks! new to stack

Comment: `sortList.sortable({` function includes an order element `order: sortList.sortable( 'toArray' ).toString(),`   How does that work?  Is that intended as a recursive function?